# History of representation theory

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

For a student's journal I want to write a short article about history and importance (applications) of representation theory. Are there some accesible literature about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could look at the two articles *Group representations and harmonic analysis from Euler to Langlands (Parts I and II)*, by A. Knapp, linked [here](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~aknapp/publications.html).

Answer (score 7):

I recall reading a bit of *Pioneers of Representation Theory* from the library and found it pleasant.

As for applications / importance, consider searching around the web for how quantum mechanics is informed by representation theory (accompanied by Lie theory). I am not sure the literature is very accessible on this subject, but I'd wager the main points could be diluted enough to be both enlightening and approachable.